# Como deletar registro com aspas simples do Mysql via PHP?

Tags: php

```
<?php

require 'conn.php';

$del_cidade = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['del_cidade']);
$pop = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['l_pop']);

$excluir = mysql_query("DELETE FROM pops WHERE pop = '$pop' AND cidade_id = '$del_cidade'");

sleep(1);
header("Location:painel_adm.php");

?>
```

Inseri através do PHP o seguinte registro "Pop Caixa D'água"(com aspas simples), consegui fazer isso escapando os caracteres com o mysql_real_escape_string. Agora preciso deletar esse registro, porém o mysql_real_escape_string não está funcionando para deletar. Como posso fazer isso?

Comment: E pq não inserir sem as aspas, mas imprimi-las somente quando for necessário?
Já tentou "\'Olá\'" OU "'Olá?'"

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro voçe deve passar tanto o mysql_real_escape_string e o Delete pela conexão

conn.php

```
$conn = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);

if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysql_connect_error());
}

mysql_set_charset($conn, 'utf8');
```

delete.php

```
require 'conn.php';

    $del_cidade = mysql_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['del_cidade']);
    $pop = mysql_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['l_pop']);

    $excluir = mysql_query($conn, "DELETE FROM pops WHERE pop = '$pop' AND cidade_id = '$del_cidade'");

    sleep(1);
    header("Location:painel_adm.php");
```